# How to get the randomized adminstrator credentials used when building images using Azure ARM and Packer

Tags: azure, powershell, credentials, azure-resource-manager, packer

During the provisioning of a `WindowsServer 2016 Datacenter` image in `Packer` using `Azure-ARM`, I need the randomly generated password used on the build VM, so that I can set the computer's domain using the code:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString $args[1] -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($args[0], $password)

Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential
```

However, I do not have access to the password generated by the Packer Build VM, and the [documentation](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/azure/arm#what-s-randomized) only states that the password is randomly generated, but not how to retrieve it.

Is there any way to get the credentials from Packer, or will I need to resort to some Powershell wizardry in an Administrator shell to get the password in plain text?

Comment: The randomly generated administrator password is for initial provisioning; especially software provisioning. You could override it then or later (possibly after the artifact is deployed with an infrastructure provisioner) if you wanted it to be deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Matt Schuchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5343387/matt-schuchard), especially for software provisioning, use the random generated admin password and override it then or later after the artifact deployed with an infra provisioner if needed to be deterministic.

> Is there any way to get the credentials from Packer , or will I need to resort to some Powershell wizardry in an Administrator shell to get the password in plain text?

Try this below code which outputs password in plain text!

***Azure PowerShell:***

```
$sp = New-AzADServicePrincipal -DisplayName "PackerSP$(Get-Random)"
$BSTR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($sp.Secret)
$plainPassword = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)
```

Then output the password and application ID.

```
    $plainPassword
    $sp.ApplicationId
```

For more details refer this **[documentation-of-build-images-with-packer-arm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/build-image-with-packer)**